# Effect of nerve pills and relationship to Shingles

Tags: human-biology, virus, medicine

Do nerve pills actually suppress the nervous system and how would that effect the Shingles virus which is known to activate under large amounts of stress?

Comment: Please be a bit more specific. What type/brand of "nerve pills" are you referring to?

Comment: Aren't all nerve pills made to calm your nerves but say Xanax to throw one out there.

Answer (score 1):

I gather you are talking about anti-axiety drugs ([anxiolytics](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Anxiolytic)). [Benzodiazepines](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Benzodiazepine) is one of the major groups of anxiolytics, and includes Xanax. Benzodiazepines are [central nervous depressants](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Central_nervous_system_depressants), meaning that they reduce the activity of [neurotransmitters](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Neurotransmitter) in the brain. They do this by binding to the GABA-A receptor and enhancing the effect of the inhibitory neurotransmitter [GABA](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gamma-Aminobutyric_acid) when it binds to the same receptor. The binding of GABA to a GABA receptor on a neuron causes hyperpolarization of the neuron by ion flow through the cellular membrane and decreases the chance of an [action potential](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Action_potential). So yes, nerve pills act by supressing the nervous system.

As for your question about interaction with Shingles, I think that's considered off-topic under the personal medical questions policy.

Comment: What makes you decide that that is a personal medical question?  If suppression of the nervous system would affect shingles, its a valid question.  As shingles affects the nervous system, its a valid question.  Saying that its under the "personal" medical questions policy is a cop out. But good answer on the first part.

Comment: I'm not deciding that it is, just giving my opinion. Others may disagree, but in any case I'm not capable of answering that question.

Comment: @jody it's borderline, it's not strictly a medical question but if we answer it someone could use it as "medical advice" and end up doing something stupid. And saying someone is using it as a cop out is not a very good way of showing gratitude.